# Do car rental companies have franchise system?

Tags: car-rentals

Do international car rental companies like avis, thrifty etc. have  franchise system or do they have their own fleet in each country/city/location?

Answer (score 5):

Most major international car rental companies use a mix of franchise and corporate owned locations. For example, [Thrifty](https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/abouthertz/index.jsp?targetPage=CorporateProfile.jsp&c=aboutHertzCompaniesView) (itself part of Hertz) has 340 corporate locations and over 1,020 franchise locations.

Franchise information is available on each rental company's website, and a search for ["car rental franchise"](https://www.google.com/search?q=car%20rental%20franchise&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab) will provide more information, including articles for and by franchise owners.

Comment: its funny that one can find thrifty and hertz in same terminal. And again Budget and Avis belong to the same parent company